# I have some CSV data and I want to import into django models using DB relationship

Tags: python, django, database, csv

Thank you in advance. I have a Django database with some models:

```
class District(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField("Code".encode('utf-8'),max_length=512, null=True)    
    name = models.CharField("Name".encode('utf-8'),max_length=512)

class Neighborhood(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField("Code".encode('utf-8'),max_length=512, null=True)    
    name = models.CharField("Name".encode('utf-8'),max_length=512)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dHab = models.DecimalField("Densiy of Habitants".encode('utf-8'),max_digits=15, decimal_places=5, default=0, validators = [MinValueValidator(0)])
```

And I need to import a csv file uploading both District and Neighborhood data.

```
01 District 1
02 District 2
03 District 3

011 Neigborhood a (Belongs to District 1)
012 Neigborhood b (Belongs to District 1)
021 Neigborhood c (Belongs to District 2)
031 Neigborhood d (Belongs to District 3)
etc.
```

If I upload a Neighborhood, how do I find the proper District before inserting into the database so they can be correctly related to each other? Because I far as I know, Django has an auto_increment field

Comment: you can create dict with like `csv_data: db_pk` and use it while insert `Neighborhood`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the districts will be in order, you could hold a reference to them and use them later. For example:

```
district_1 = District.objects.create(....)
# Use this to create the neighborhood
Neighborhood.objects.create(district=district_1, ....)
```

In this sense, you do not need to care about the primary key of the object because you already have a reference to it.

Conversely, you could fetch the district object using any field (not just the primary key).

```
district_1 = District.objects.get(name="District 1")
```